Is there an L-system representation for Polya's Triangle Sweep?
I am currently reading the book "The Fractal Geometry of Nature" by Benoit Mandelbrot. I tried to write a program to visualize some of the curves found in the book by using L-system replacement methods. For some of the curves one can find the rules quite easily, however for this curve I was not able to. Does anyone have a clue?
I included a screenshot of the generator displayed in the book. Any help would be appreciated!
Generator of Polya's triangle sweep

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

According to this page, the equivalent L-system would be:
Axiom: L
L = L+R-L-R
R = L+R+L-R

For which we can write a short Python turtle program to confirm:
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

AXIOM = "L"

RULES = {
    'L': "L+R-L-R",
    'R': "L+R+L-R"
}

LEVELS = 5
DISTANCE = 40

string = AXIOM

for _ in range(LEVELS):
    string = "".join(RULES.get(character, character) for character in string)

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.speed(0)  # because I have no patience

for character in string:
    if character in '-+':
        turtle.right([-90, 90][character == '+'])
    else:
        turtle.forward(DISTANCE / LEVELS)

screen.exitonclick()



Hi, thanks :). This solution effectively combines two iterations (from the generator I posted) into one and thereby it becomes expressable as an L-system. Simple, but I would never have thought of that!
